# RSpec: undefined method for #<ActionController::TestResponse. Testing a dynamic flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a simple spec testing the creation of an object of the Baseline class.

```
 it "allows a user to create a baseline score with valid content" do
  expect(@user.baselines.count).to eq(0)
  @baseline = post(:create, :user_id => @user.id, :baseline => valid_attributes)
  expect(response).to redirect_to '/patients/list'
  expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Baseline scores for case #{@baseline.case_id} was successfully created.")
  expect(Baseline.all.count).to eq(1)
 end
```

But I get this. I am uncertain where to begin with this - I am uncertain why I can't access the case_id attribute of @baseline.

```
   NoMethodError:undefined method `case_id' for <ActionController::TestResponse:0x007f8f5ab4f3c0>
```

Just to show...these are the valid attributes

```
 let(:valid_attributes) do {
    :dx1 => "IPF",
    :dxcon1 => 100,
    :db1 => "Progressive",
    :dbcon1 => 100,
    :mgt=> "Drugs",
    :biopsy => "Yes",
    :patient_id => @patient.id,
    :case_id => @patient.case,
    }
 end
```

Comment: Hey in the @baseline = post(:create, :user_id => ...)  you have not mentioned case_id column, whether case_id column gets auto generated ?

Comment: After  @baseline = post(:create, :user_id => ...) try printing  baseline object. See if post is returning valid base line object or not.

Answer (score 2):

`post` doesn't return a model instance it returns a TestResponse object which gives you access to headers, status code, etc.  To access the object created as a side effect of calling the :create action you can do `Baseline.last`  (in this case Baseline.first would also work since there are no existing baseline objects)

Also note - if you have an instance variable named @baseline that is assigned in the controller you can access that with `assigns(:baseline)`

```
expect(assigns[:baseline]).to be_a(Baseline)
```

Comment: Many thanks. So how would you get access to the created object?

Comment: Since there were no previous baselines - `Baseline.first` would  give you the created instance

Comment: Yes. I used that and it works. Just hoped there was a more specific way. If I was to create more than one baseline it starts to get messy.

Comment: In that case Baseline.last would always the be the last one created, and most likely the one you're wanting to check things about.

Comment: Clever. Can you edit this in your answer and I'll mark